# Icon associated with extension

Tags: macos, icon, file-extensions

I'm running Mountain Lion, and my question is how to "attach" an icon to an extension? For example, I want all .adm files has an icon like on the picture below. Unfortunately all I can is just attach an icon to proper file, not to all files that has such extension. Thus I want .adm extension has their own icon. .adm is opening in TextEdit, so please don't suggest me to open it in right app. Thank you in advance![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this detailed answer for "How to set an icon for a file type on Mac?" on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/225534).

In this case, you need to update TextEdit's resources and plist to get it to use your custom icon for a file type it does not know about. The LaunchServices database also needs to be updated for the changes to be seen.

Here's a small snippet from that answer (bold emphasis mine):

> Icons for file types are handled by Launch Services (the service determining, among other things, which application handles a file type). **The file icon is always provided by the application handling opening a file by default. This way, e.g. Preview provides PDF icons by default, and PNG icons, but if you change all PNG files to open using Pixelmator instead, these files get a Pixelmator-style icon afterwards.**
>
> What you need to do is *add your file type definition to the application that opens it by default, or create your own "dummy" application for the file type.*