# Edit plist file for TextEdit

Tags: permission, plist, textedit

I need to edit plist file of TextEdit (TextEdit/Contents/plist.info) for doing [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104203/58740), using Xcode. But TextEdit says that I've got no permission for edit [image]

[image]

I've tried to get more permission for me, so I inscribed myself in GetInfo (Pasha is me). [image]

But still the same problem as on the pictures above. I was searching for an answer and found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/68648/58740). As you can see, this answer suggests me to do what I've already done. So I hope you know the different solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you please add a bit more details like which plist file you are trying to edit, what the Get Info dialog for that files shows in terms of permissions and which answer to the question you linked doesn't work and why? Add as much detail as you can think of, we love details here.

Comment: Did you give yourself write permissions to the folder the plist is in as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to have write permission to the directory the file is in:

```
sudo chown $USER /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist
sudo chown $USER /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents
```

After you have edited the file, change the owner of the plist and the directory back to root:

```
sudo chown root /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist
sudo chown root /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents
```

You could also run `cp /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist ~/Desktop/` (which changes the owner to you), edit the file on the desktop, and then run `sudo cp ~/Desktop/Info.plist /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist` (which changes the owner back to root).

Or use another editor:

```
sudo nano /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Comment: after I added new item to "Document Types" in "Info.plist" of TextEdit (no matter what this item contents, even empty) the application fails to open. As soon as I delete the extra string, app immediately starts working.

Comment: Comments shouldn't bei used to ask questions, please create a new question describing what you are trying to do and how it fails.

Comment: @littlenimrod Oh, I forgot about that. Since 10.8, sandboxed applications (like TextEdit, Chess, or applications downloaded from the App Store) have crashed on launch if their Info.plist has been modified. I don't know any workarounds for it, but there is [a non-sandboxed version of TextEdit](https://github.com/jjgod/TextEditPlus) on Github.

Answer (score 0):

After all these steps, open Terminal and run

```
sudo codesign -fs - /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app
```